# How can I escape special characters in regex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, escaping

I'm developing a simple chat bot and I'm having some trouble escaping special characters using .replace - I might be missing the obvious but the code below doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

To clarify, this code works and does what I want it to do without the .replace line but I need it so if a user types ? or ! etc it won't matter.

```
    var know = {
<!--General Phrases-->  
"Hi": "Hello! &#128075",
"Hey": "Hello! &#128075",
"Hello":"Hello &#128075 How can I help?",    
"how are you":"Not bad, thanks!",
"Bye":"Have a nice day!",
"Goodbye":"See you later!", 

<!--Directory-->
"Help": `You can find help by searching below or by clicking <a href='https://www.page.com/news' target="_blank">here</a>`,
"contact":  `You can contact us by clicking <a href='https://www.page.com/contact' target="_blank">here</a>`,
"About": `You can find our About Us page by clicking <a href='https://www.page.com/about' target="_blank">here</a>` 
};

function goo() {
 var userBox = document.getElementById('userBox');
 var userInput = userBox.value;
 var chatLog = document.getElementById('chatLog');
 var chatLogContent = "";

 if (!userInput) {
     chatLogContent = ''
 }

 var hasKeyword = false;

 for (var key in know) {
      if (userInput.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~ ()]/g,"").match(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+key.toLowerCase()+'(\\s|$)')))  {{
          hasKeyword = true;
          break;
      } else {
          hasKeyword = false;
      }
 }

if (hasKeyword) {
    chatLogContent += know[key] + "<br>"; //or use know.key
} else {
    chatLogContent += "No results found. Please enter another search term below.<br>";
}

var server = document.createElement('div');
server.setAttribute('class', 'server');
server.innerHTML = chatLogContent;
document.getElementById('chatLog').innerHTML = '';
chatLog.appendChild(server);
}
```

UPDATE: This has been solved. Please see Wiktor Stribiżew's answer in the comments.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks for the help, basically, I want it so if a user types "how are you?" it'll match the same answer that's for they key "how are you" - I think I'd need to remove them from both values?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Would I then call escapeRegex(); above hasKeyword = true; ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I did initially do it this way by splitting it but regex seemed better. Here was my previous code -  if (userInput.toLowerCase()
      .replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~ ()]/g,"")
      .split(/\s+/)
      .includes(key.toLowerCase())) 

This worked, but couldn't find multiple words and picked up on "hi" in "high" etc.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the link, I did try it this way but it doesn't pick up multiple words. The code I have above in my post does exactly what I want it to do with the exception of ignoring special characters. Could I ask if you can show me what the solution for this should look like?

Comment: Then  do it as I mentioned in the top comment, remove them from `key.toLowerCase()`, too. Replace `key.toLowerCase()` with ``key.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"")``. Ah, remove the space, I do not think you want to remove spaces since you need to identify multiple words. Both replacements must look like ``.replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"")``. If you need to add a backslash, double it, ``.replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()\\]/g,"")``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much, it is now working fully! :) I really appreciate your patience and the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```js
if (userInput.toLowerCase().replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~ ()]/g,"").match(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+key.toLowerCase()+'(\\s|$)')))  {{
```

you remove spaces (there is a space in the character class in `` /[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~ ()]/g ``). That is why your regex (that you build with `new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+key.toLowerCase()+'(\\s|$)')`) matches only when the string is equal to key, it expects the `key` in between whitespaces or start/end of string.

You need to remove the space from replacement and apply this operation both on the input and key:

```js
if (userInput.replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()\\]/g,"").match(new RegExp('(^|\\s)'+key.replace(/[.,\/#!$%^&*;:{}=\-_`~()\\]/g,"")+'(\\s|$)', 'i')))  {{
```

Note `^` and `;` need no escaping. I also added a backslash to the special char character class.

Note there is no need to turn the case to lower, you can simply pass the `i` case insensitive flag to regex.